# How long can I expect that youtube api v.3 is maintained?

Tags: web-services, api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm looking at youtube api v.3 for a project for a client. They want to know for how long the applicaiton will work without maintenance. Is there any dates presented for how long api v.3 will be supported, or at least a version history for when the previous api:s where created and depricated?

Comment: Ask Google for this. Why don't you send an email to their support team?

Comment: The word on the street is that it's hard to get in touch with google...

Comment: Also, this is where youtube sends you if you click ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=youtube-api

Comment: But think that SO isn't YouTube support team... Sending an email to Google is worth the effort.

Comment: I see, but BTW I believe this isn't the kind of question that requires know-how, but just an ad hoc answer from the company. It seems like here you'll find support if you ask for something like how to perform an API call, or why you get an exception using client SDK and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=de#deprecation):

> Deprecation.
>
> Google will announce if it intends to discontinue or make backwards
>   incompatible changes to this API or Service. Google will use
>   commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate those YouTube
>   API versions and features identified at
>   http://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list without these
>   changes until the later of: (i) one year after the announcement or
>   (ii) April 20, 2015, unless (as Google determines in its reasonable
>   good faith judgment):
>
> required by law or third party relationship (including if there is a
>   change in applicable law or relationship), or doing so could create a
>   security risk or substantial economic or material technical burden.
>   The above policy is the "Deprecation Policy."